# Euclid the Game Level 2: Construct a line that bisects the given angle.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

This is the level I'm trying to complete:

[image]

---

My last idea was this, but I still don't get a message that I completed the level.

[image]

Why is this not correct ? Last time I did mathematics was 10 years ago, sorry if this is a real noob question, but I just don't see how to complete this level.

Edit: You can find the level here http://euclidthegame.org/Level2.html

Comment: This is an awesome game, by the way. Neat find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You can create this midpoint with the tool you unlocked in level 1: "Constructing equilateral triangles"

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be choosing D as the midpoint of BC, which would work. Except that the game doesn't have a midpoint function so you're creating that point - not guaranteeing that it will be the midpoint.

Think if you can use circles in some way to find a point equidistant from B and C. If you can do that, you're set!